# open spherical camera - find camera ip address

Tags: c#, networking, unity-game-engine, panoramas, 360-panorama

I am trying to make an app that works with OSC API 360 cameras. It's an api that you connect to a camera like it's a wifi router, and control it in the HTTP way. The problems is, 360 cameras seem like don't have a standard on the ip address. For now i know that :

Gear360 uses 192.168.107.1
Bublcam uses 192.168.0.100
RICO THETA uses 192.168.1.1

To make my app easy to use, it has to automatically get the ip address. Is there a way to do that instead of having a hardcoded list of every device?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: i ping every ip on my list. if it still can't find the 360 camera, then i ping from 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.255.255. I think there is a boardcast way to do that but i haven't tried

Comment: Thanks for that. On further investigation it appears that once you're connected to the camera it's the Gateway IP address you need to query in order to get the correct IP for the camera. There are a number of examples out there to do that, all seem to be ObjC based.

Comment: @RichardPoole can you share the link of this Objc examples/?

Comment: @SunnyChow Any luck on finding the ip address?

Answer (score 0):

try to use [nmap](https://www.google.az/search?q=nmap%20for%20windows&oq=nmap%20&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.3863j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and search from

```
nmap 192.168.0.0-999
```